# How to invoke Google Drive REST API with Jersey?

Tags: java, jersey, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to use Java Jersey instead of Google client libraries to access the Google File API, but I keep getting returned a response status of "401 Unauthorized". Prior to invoking the call, I have obtained an access token from Google, using Oauth:

```
public static String getGoogleFileResource(final String fileId,
        final String accessToken) {
    //projection

    ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
    cc.getProperties().put(ClientConfig.PROPERTY_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, true);
    Client client = Client.create(cc);

    String url = String
            .format("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/%s?fields=downloadUrl&key=%s",
                    fileId, GoogleClientConstants.GOOGLE_api_key);
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);

    String response = webResource
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE,
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
            .get(String.class);

    logger.info("Authorization - " + "Bearer " + accessToken);
    logger.info(" reponse " + response);
    return response;
}
```

What am  I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to add your access token to the http request header.

In the Google developer's guide: "uploading a file"

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

You need to send a post request like this:

```
POST /upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_JPEG_file
Authorization: your_auth_token

JPEG data
```

note that in the header you need to put a your_auth_token